# How do i Replicate the DB using sitecore?

Tags: publishing, publishing-targets

We have 2 Environments say a CM server and a CD server.
The CD server is in different region far from CM DB.

So we have a replicated DB for CD server in same CD servers region. Right now this is Sql Replication and we have to get rid of the Sql Replication for some reasons.

Is there any other way where I can publish the item whenever it is changed in the CM server?

Or any other better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use [Publishing Targets](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/all-about-publishing-targets-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms).

Essentially you can publish to one or more target "web" databases. It would show up as additional checkboxes whenever you publish from your CM.

You set up a new Publishing Target by adding it under `/system/Publishing Targets`

[image]

You then specify a `Target Database`. Add a connection string to match it in your `ConnectionStrings.Config`.

[image]

If you want this process to happen automatically, you should utilise a Sitecore Workflow set up for [automatic publishing](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/latest_technical_reinnovations/posts/auto-publish-workflow-action-updates).